# Rspec and System Interaction

Tags: ruby, testing, operating-system, mocking, rspec

I have a program that will be running several system commands. The simplest way I know how to do this is with the ` ` notation. I'd like to build tests for these tools without it actually having to run those system commands on the system.

Is there a way I can mock the response from the system?

Comment: what about writing wrappers for these system commands? and then mock the repsonses from them.

Comment: That would work as a fall back, but 9 times out of 10 I've found that Ruby has some simple magic command that will solve all my problems. I hope this isn't the first time it's not. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your code runs a lot of external commands you should create a simple wrapper and mock that:

```
def wants_to_run_external_command(command_runner)
  command_runner.run('echo "hello world"')
end
```

and test it like this:

```
it 'echos "hello world"' do
  command_runner = double()
  command_runner.should_receive(:run).with('echo "hello world"')
  subject.wants_to_run_external_command(command_runner)
end
```

If you want to be neater you initialize your object with the command runner instance so you don't have to pass it to the method, of course.